# Only last result from ResultSet showing in ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, resultset

I am trying to store values from ResultSet into an ArrayList. But when I print the values of the ArrayList only the last value stored is displayed for the total number of times.

[image]

```
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);

        while (rs.next()) {

            user.setF_number(rs.getInt("F_NUMBER"));
            user.setId(rs.getString("ID"));
            user.setFirst_name(rs.getString("FIRST_NAME"));
            user.setMsg_date(rs.getString("MSG_DATE"));
            user.setTopic_id(rs.getInt("TOPIC_ID"));
            user.setMessage(rs.getString("MESSAGE"));
            System.out.println(rs.getString("MESSAGE"));
            users.add(user);
        }

        Iterator itr = users.listIterator();
        while (itr.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(itr.next());
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each time you iterate the while loop you should instantiate a new `User` object.Otherwise you get only the last result as the out come.

```
while (rs.next()) {
            User user = new User();//this should be inside while loop
            user.setF_number(rs.getInt("F_NUMBER"));
            user.setId(rs.getString("ID"));
            user.setFirst_name(rs.getString("FIRST_NAME"));
            user.setMsg_date(rs.getString("MSG_DATE"));
            user.setTopic_id(rs.getInt("TOPIC_ID"));
            user.setMessage(rs.getString("MESSAGE"));
            System.out.println(rs.getString("MESSAGE"));
            users.add(user);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope you are creating the user object outside the while loop

so user details are overriden

you need to create a differnet user object for different record and that that user object to arrayList like the following

```
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);

        while (rs.next()) {
User user=new User()
            user.setF_number(rs.getInt("F_NUMBER"));
            user.setId(rs.getString("ID"));
            user.setFirst_name(rs.getString("FIRST_NAME"));
            user.setMsg_date(rs.getString("MSG_DATE"));
            user.setTopic_id(rs.getInt("TOPIC_ID"));
            user.setMessage(rs.getString("MESSAGE"));
            System.out.println(rs.getString("MESSAGE"));
            users.add(user);
        }

        Iterator itr = users.listIterator();
        while (itr.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(itr.next());
        }
```